# Where can I find actual agricultural contracts?

Tags: data-request, usa, finance, economics, legal

I'm looking for real agricultural contracts, that is actual contracts between farmers and processors (preferably in North America). Any ideas?

Generally I am thinking of contracts between farmers and middlemen. One example that has been in the news recently has been contracts between poultry growers and processors like Tyson and Perdue.

Comment: Could you please detail what you mean by processors? It would be great if you could give some examples of various processors. This might help us when searching.

Comment: Sure! Generally I am thinking of contracts between farmers and middlemen. One example that has been in the news recently has been contracts between poultry growers and processors like Tyson and Perdue.